# How to create a binary hand mask in web browser? - open CV

Tags: opencv, web, browser, typescript-typings

I am trying to create a binary hand mask base on this article : https://medium.com/@muehler.v/simple-hand-gesture-recognition-using-opencv-and-javascript-eb3d6ced28a0

But I use a new version of OpenCV compiled as JavaScript for web browsers. In my OpenCV version cv.Vector does not exist. I don't know how to replace the `cv.Vector` function. I have been trying to rewrite functions `skinColorUpper`, `skinColorLower`. However, the effect is not satisfactory. How can I write these functions correctly?

```js
const canvasInput = document.getElementById("canvasInput");
const canvasOutput = document.getElementById("canvasOutput");

const skinColorUpper = (hue) => new cv.Mat(1, 1, cv.CV_8UC4,new cv.Scalar(hue,0.8 * 255, 0.6 * 255));
const skinColorLower = (hue) => new cv.Mat(1, 1, cv.CV_8UC4,new cv.Scalar(hue,0.1 * 255, 0.05 * 255));

const img = cv.imread(canvasInput);
cv.cvtColor( img, imgHLS, cv.COLOR_BGR2HLS);
const rangeMask = new cv.Mat();
const up = skinColorUpper(15);
const low = skinColorLower(0);

cv.inRange(imgHLS, low, up, rangeMask);

cv.imshow(canvasOutput, rangeMask);
```

Input:
[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z0L3.png)

HLS:
[HLS image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3n7z.png)

Output:
[output mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8WzB.png)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function openCvReady() {
  cv['onRuntimeInitialized']=()=> {
    let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');

    let hls = new cv.Mat();
    cv.cvtColor(src, hls, cv.COLOR_BGR2HLS);

    let low = new cv.Mat(hls.rows, hls.cols, hls.type(), [0, 0.1 * 255, 0.05 * 255, 0]);
    let high = new cv.Mat(hls.rows, hls.cols, hls.type(), [15, 0.8 * 255, 0.6 * 255, 255]);

    let dst = new cv.Mat();

    cv.inRange(hls, low, high, dst);

    cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
  };
}
```

Look here on [Github](https://github.com/ippon1/javascript-finger-gestures-recognition/blob/master/index.html).